# For loop in javascript on mongoshell

Tags: javascript, mongodb, for-loop

I have 2 collections in my database

```
MongoDB Enterprise> show collections
mycoll1 
mycoll2
```

I want to pass these names to a variable say c1 and use values of this array in mongodb shell commands (here getting counts from collections). what I'm doing now is:

```
MongoDB Enterprise> for (var i in c1) { db.getCollection((c1[i])).find().count()}
```

but in output I'm getting only second collections count and not first one.

I'm new to javascrip: please suggest.

Comment: `for ( var i of c1 )` `in` keys the "keys" of an object. Also see [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) for details on what the differences are.

Comment: you mean to say I need to use like this:
for (var i of c1) { db.getCollection((c1[i])).find().count()}

Comment: `for (var i of db.getCollectionNames()) { print(db.getCollection(i).find().count()); }`

Comment: when I use  for (var i in c1) { print(c1[i]) } it prints both values i.e. mycoll1 and mycoll2

but when I use for (var i of c1) { print(c1[i]) } it shows 
[unknown type]
[unknown type]